# SQL Query: Retrieve matching records from two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I am a complete beginner in SQL. I used to work a little with it 5 years ago.

Here's the deal: I'm on Ms Access. I have a table `Table1` where one field has a number which is the `id` of an entry in another table `Table2`.

I run a query with the `id` of the entries in `Table1` and I also want the query to return entries from `Table2` for matching `Id` from `Table1`.

Is it possible?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.  This is very basic SQL.  I would recommend that you find a tutorial of some sort to re-learn the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use approach which you feel good any of given below.

Using sub query..

```
SELECT t2.* FROM table2 AS t2
WHERE t2.id in (SELECT t1.id FROM Table1 AS t1)
```

Using join ..

```
SELECT t2.* FROM table2 AS t2
INNER JOIN table1 AS t1
ON t2.id=t1.id
```

Comment: Thanks very much i forgot that subquerys existed, they are exactly what i need!

Answer (score 0):

yes, there are plenty of tutorials of how to join data in SQL. What you've described is exactly why SQL is powerful - allows you to link data between different tables based on conditions you specify.

The join you are looking for is

```
INNER join 
SELECT * FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
ON t2.id=t1.id
```